# turn off css spinner if toggle switch is flicked off in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have a toggle switch and spinner on my page. I want for the spinner to stop spinning or disappear when the toggle switch is flicked off. I believe I need some kind of javascript  for this but a I am a newbie. Please assist in writing javascript for this on how to execute the spinner based on the .switch value.

.html page

> ```
>  @keyframes spinner {
>  0% {
>  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(0deg);
>  }
>   }
>  100% {
>  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(360deg);
>  }
> .switch {
> position: relative;
> display: inline-block;
> width: 55px;
> height: 28px;
> }
> .spin::before {
>  animation: 1.5s linear infinite spinner;  
>  animation-play-state: inherit;   
>  border: solid 5px #cfd0d1;  
>  border-bottom-color: #1c87c9;   
>  border-radius: 50%;   content: "";  
>  height: 20px;   width: 20px;   
>  position: absolute;   
>  top: 26%;   left:
>  35%;   
>  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);   
>  will-change:
>  transform; }
>
> .switch {   position: relative;   display: inline-block;   width:
>  55px;   height: 28px; }
>
> .slider {
>   position: absolute;
>   cursor: pointer;
>   top: 0;
>   left: 0;
>   right: 0;
>   bottom: 0;
>   background-color: #ccc;
>   -webkit-transition: .4s;
>   transition: .4s;
> }
>
> .slider:before {
>   position: absolute;
>   content: "";
>   height: 20px;
>   width: 20px;
>   left: 4px;
>   bottom: 4px;
>   background-color: white;
>   -webkit-transition: .4s;
>   transition: .4s;
> }
>
> input:checked + .slider {
>   background-color: #2196F3;
> }
>
> input:focus + .slider {
>   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
> }
>
> input:checked + .slider:before {
>   -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
>   -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
>   transform: translateX(26px);
> }
>
> <span class="slider round"></span>
> <div class="spin"></div>
> ```

Comment: The first `@keyframes spinner` block in the posted code seems to be missing a `}`.

Comment: It would be useful to see more of the HTML. Where is the toggle switch?

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you can remove an element like this:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("div.spin"); // your css query here
el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
```

I find hiding it is sometimes better (in case you need to reveal the loading again later):

```js
const el = document.querySelector("div.spin"); // your css query here
el.style.display = "non"; // hide using CSS display
```

You'd want to put this code on the `onclick` handler for the input (which I don't believe you have in your code). If it is a button, you could do it like so:

```html
<button onclick="const el = document.querySelector('div.spin');el.parentElement.removeChild(el);">Click to remove element</button>
```

There are many ways to embed JavaScript in your HTML websites; for more info, I'd recommend reading the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: please help me with where to put this code. I tried adding const el = document.querySelector("div.spin"); before  @keyframes spinner section and el.style.display = "non"; after it but it doesn't work.

Comment: I want the spinner to turn off or hide when the slider is toggled off. Their is no button.

Comment: Javascript is not runnable inside the `<style>` tag. You must wrap it in a `<script>` tag, or use the inline sytax I put in the `<button>`'s `onclick` attribute. Try pasting the button code in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It can be good to separate HTML and JavaScript. Instead of having, in your HTML, `<button onclick="some javascript code">`, You could have `<button id="my-toggle-btn">`.

Then your JavaScript code could go inside an HTML *script* element on the same page as your HTML like this:

```
<script>
  const myToggleBtn = document.querySelector('#my-toggle-btn');
  myToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // some more javascript code
  });
</script>
```

The other way is to put that javascript code in a file for example *main.js*. Then you could include that file's contents by having a *script* element in the *head* element of your HTML:

```
<head>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Most people use a mix of all these approaches depending on the situation. It is important to know about all of them.

Comment: Was hoping for a full script that works with he current toggle and spinner elements. When toggle is clicked it turns of the spinner.